# Makefile issue - No rule to make target 'gcc'

Tags: c, makefile

I have just started learning make and I am having some trouble. I want to create an executable called sortfile. Here are the relevant files: `sortfile.c fileio.c fileio.h`

Both `sortfile.c` and `fileio.c` use `fileio.h`.

Here is my makefile:

```
  1 CC = gcc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  2 CFLAGS = -g -Wall                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  4 default: sortfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  6 sortfile: sortfile.o fileio.o $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o sortfile sortfile.o fileio.o                                                                                                                                                             
  7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  8 sortfile.o: sortfile.c fileio.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c sortfile.c                                                                                                                                                                             
  9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 10 fileio.o: fileio.c fileio.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c fileio.c                                                                                                                                                                                   
 11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 12 clean:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 13         $(RM) sortfile *.o*~
```

I am getting the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `gcc', needed by `sortfile.o'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makefiles are of the format:

```
target: dependency1 dependency2
    rule (command to build)
```

You listed the command as the set of dependencies, so `make` wants to try to build `gcc` before it can expect `sortfile.o` to be satisfied.

Instead of:

```
sortfile.o: sortfile.c fileio.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c sortfile.c
```

you need:

```
sortfile.o: sortfile.c fileio.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c sortfile.c
```

Note that normally all you really want here is something much simpler:

```
CFLAGS+=-g -Wall
all: sortfile
sortfile: sortfile.o fileio.o
```

This brief `Makefile` will work as expected with GNU Make because of implicit rules ([see also](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)).

Comment: Inserting a semicolon between the end of the prerequisite list and before the command will also work (i.e. `sortfile: sortfile.o fileio.o ; $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o sortfile sortfile.o fileio.o`).

Comment: If we run out of carriage returns, that could be really handy!  ;)